# buckets in std::unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

Say I have an `std::unordered_multiset<int>` which is named `hashTable` and a bucket `i`. Can I iterate through the elements of the `i`th bucket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can indeed iterate through each bucket, using local iterators:

```
for (auto it = hashTable.cbegin(i); it != hashTable.cend(i); ++it)
{
    // ... use *it
}
```

Be sure that `i` lies in the range `[0, hashTable.bucket_count())`.

Comment: must be stressed that cbegin(i) may not always be valid and must be checked against cend(i).

Comment: @g24l: What do you mean by "not valid"? Do you mean "not dereferenceable"?

Comment: come on you are smarter than that.